# kerberos multi user login in an already logged-in instance

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, redhat, kerberos, spnego

We are trying to implement kerberos backed by ldap for our application.
We have a scenario where user1 (associate) logins onto machine1 and clicks on applicationA, now user2 (manager) needs to login into applicationA on the same machine1 to approve/correct something. If I some how manage to implement a logout link, can I achieve logging out from kerberos for the user1 and shoe him a form login to use his ldap credentials?

Any help or sources is greatly appreciated. I have search here and over the internet without any success.

We are using Red Hat EAP 7, Red Hat SSO 7.1, Primefaces 6.0, CDI 1.2, JAVAEE7, Java 1.8, Windows 7, Active Directory

Edit: added more environment details.

Comment: _"Kerberos backed by LDAP"_ does not make much sense; Kerberos is an authentication protocol, LDAP is a kind of database that is often used to manage authorizations (i.e. access privileges). They are completely distinct things -- although many LDAP systems also provide an embedded Kerberos KDC to cover both authentication & authorization (e.g. Active Directory, OpenLDAP).

Comment: _"logging out from Kerberos"_ makes no sense. You don't "log" into Kerberos; you contact a KDC service to obtain an ticket (a proof of identity, with limited lifetime) that you can present to a specific kerberized service. Every running program may have its own private ticket. Or, multiple programs running on the same host under the same OS user may share the same ticket, using a ticket cache. But multple users logged on the same host will have distinct tickets.

Comment: And Single-Sign-On just means that the Kerberos ticket obtained when opening the current OS session (in the LSA cache for Windows/AD, in a `/tmp` file or in the system KeyRing for Linux using SSSD) is used automatically by applications running inside that session.

Comment: "Kerberos backed by LDAP", I meant that Kerberos server is using ldap to verify the authneticity of the user. So, does it mean I can use Kerberos or ldap

Comment: Sorry my earlier comment was unfinished.. "Kerberos backed by LDAP", Yes our AD is embedded with Kerberos KDC. I understand that a user can automatically login into an application using kerberos but when I want a different user to login into the same application without logging-off that user from windows can I use ldap. Is there a way to switch the authentication process when logout is used.

Comment: Again, **LDAP does not handle authentication**. And SSO is a *convenience*, it's not mandatory -- every application **may** ask for the login/password to use. Just like you can connect to a network drive with a generic account (cf. `net use`).

Comment: Sorry Samson, may be I am not explaining you right. Yes, I have configured ldap in my application, it uses windows credentials to login into my application. I have even configured kerberos for my application. Right now my application defaults to use kerberos to login (it automatically gets into my application, using the ticket) into my application. My question is can I configure it in such a way that I can decide which one to use?

Comment: I am not a magician. You never cared to explain which kind of framework and/or language you use. The Kerberos libraries for Java, Python, C#, C++, etc are widely different, especially on Windows, as Microsoft uses very specific extensions to Kerberos in AD (cf. SSPI libraries whereas Java only supports GSSAPI).

Comment: I have missed the operating system, I added the more environment details in my actual post.